# podio , How do I get all items with certain field value

Tags: podio

I need to get all items with active-house set to active, So instead of getting all items and test if the active-house is set to active, like this:

```
    $items = PodioItem::filter($app_id,array('external_id'=>array('active-house')));
    $today_active=array();
    foreach($items as $item){
    $fields=$item->fields;

            foreach($fields as $f){
                if($f->external_id=='active-house'){
                    print_r($f->values);
                    if($f->values[0]['text']=='Active'){
                        $today_active[]=$item->title;
                    }
                }

            }
    }
```

I need to filter only the ones with active-house set to active, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Handmade way** — use [filter by view](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-by-view-4540284). First you set up filters and save them as a view in Podio ([manually](https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201019638-Views-filters-and-reports) or [via API](https://developers.podio.com/doc/views/create-view-27453)). It could be a team view or a private one, it does not matter. And then you just get already filtered items from that view:

```
    $items = PodioItem::filter_by_view( $app_id, $view_id, $attributes);
```

See the documentation here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-by-view-4540284

This way is useful if you want users/admins to control results of your script without any coding — they can just edit the view.

2) **API-only way** — use fields in filter. Note that not all field types can be used for filtering, i.e. text fields cannot be used. Here is an example for a category field with multi-selection:

```
    $attributes = array(
        "filters" => array(
            $field_id => array(1,2,4) // 1,2,4 - IDs of needed category values
        )
    );

    $items = PodioItem::filter($app_id, $attributes);
```

See the documentation on how to filter other field types: https://developers.podio.com/doc/filters